# How to enumerate a process's modules?

Tags: winapi

My application creates a suspended process, gets process's information via VirtualQueryEx() ,but fails getting process's module information using EnumProcessModules().

The task above is completed ONLY if the process is NOT created suspended and a breakpoint is hit in the debugger(so the program runs, before the call is executed).

I'm trying to write a very decent disassembler and for that I would need to run a target process suspended, but EnumProcessModules() does not work on suspended processes.

Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

I dealt with something like this several years ago. If I remember right, what I ended up doing was creating the task suspended, then `GetThreadContext`, set its trap flag, `SetThreadContext`, resume the thread (which runs one instruction), then use `EnumProcessModules`.

Of course, there may be other ways to handle this, but at least if memory serves, that's what I came up with at the time and I seem to recall its working.

Comment: After I resume the thread, the program executes as normal, not only one instruction. The trap flag is set to 0x100.